# SQL Server query disk write/sec limit

Tags: sql-server

I am facing an issue which it looks like the server is hitting disk write limit. But after some test, I realize it wasn't. I was running the following query:

```
DECLARE @MyCounter int;
SET @MyCounter = 0;

SET NOCOUNT ON;

WHILE (@MyCounter < 10000)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES ('testing text', 99)
   SET @MyCounter = @MyCounter + 1;
END
```

The following shows some print screen and explanation of my problem:

At 1st, I opened 1 query window and run the query, then I checked Performance Monitor:

[image]

It seems like I'm hitting limit of around 120 Disk Writes/sec.

Then, I opened another query window and run the same query, now I got the following Performance Monitor screen:

[image]

Ok, Disk Writes/sec limit seems increased to 240.

And again, I opened 1 more query window and run the same query again, I got the following Performance Monitor screen:

[image]

As expected, Disk Writes/sec increased to around 360.

My question is: ***Is SQL Server / Windows server / any other thing limiting this Disk Writes/sec ?*** Thanks in advance.

I'm using **SQL Server 2014** in **Windows Server 2012 R2 64-bit** running on **Dell PowerEdge 2900** server. This server has just been formatted.

Comment: You are inserting "row by row" aka "slow by slow". You'll get a lot more throughput if you turn this into a set operation, see http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1 for some ideas on how to do that.

Comment: Hi Colin, thx for your reply! My concern is on why the Disk Writes/sec is increased when I run the same query on multiple query window. So it is not hardware limitation here. It looks something like "Disk Writes/sec limitation per query" for me.

Comment: I'm guessing each session is CPU bound, and you have multiple cores.

Comment: yup, the server has 4 CPUs, they are 
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU, E5420  @ 2.50GHz

So, you are saying that each of this CPU limiting the Disk Write to about 120/sec, and I have 4 CPUs, so in max i can achieve 480 disk writes/sec ?

Comment: Change your code from "row by row" to set-based processing and you'll notice orders of magnitude improvement.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say but I'm guessing that your log files are on your D: drive and what you're seeing here is writes to the transaction log files, not to the database files i.e. to ldf not to mdf.  You won't see the mdf files written until the DB hits a `CHECKPOINT`, which could be some minutes later.

The linear increase is good and what you'd hope for.  That you can get from 120 to 240 and 360 shows that the disk subsystem is capable of these rates.  Whether the absolute number is as good as you would hope for or not, that's another matter.  I would suggest that the nature of the test you've chosen is itself limiting the whole system throughput.  Now you have populated tables you can try

```
INSERT INTO TestTable
SELECT TOP 10000 * FROM TestTable;
```

and see what rate that gives you.

Answer (score 1):

You are by no means hitting a write/sec threshold, unless you were maybe using a Commodore 64. Jokes aside, the proof it is not disk bound is that you are able to increase the throughput with each additional window. What is slowing you down is the the transaction management that makes SQL and others so popular.

Try the following approaches:

Option 1:

Wrap the entire loop in 1 transaction. This should be a magnitude faster.

```
DECLARE @MyCounter int;
SET @MyCounter = 0;

SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN TRAN --Start my tran

WHILE (@MyCounter < 10000)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES ('testing text', 99)
   SET @MyCounter = @MyCounter + 1;
END

COMMIT -- Commit my tran
```

Option 2:

```
--Look for a table with 100000 rows, say it is called Mytable
-- Or build one

INSERT INTO TestTable 
select top 100000 1 from Mytable with (nolock)
```

You will notice that the larger the number of rows you are inserting the larger the throughput on disk. Today's HW, don't be surprised SQL uses over 100MB/s. I've seen it fill the I/O controller many times on 8Gb/s cards.

Answer (score 0):

Disk Writes/sec depends on disk specification. For an array system, the values shown are for all disks. So, there is no specific threshold, nor it's limited by SQL Server / Windows server / any other thing.

More useful info here: [Windows Performance Monitor Disk Counters Explained](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2012/03/16/windows-performance-monitor-disk-counters-explained.aspx)